# Find which table is causing duplicate rows in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in sql server which should be returning one row per project.  A few of the projects have multiple rows.   The view has a lot of table joins so I would not like to have to manually run a script on each table to find out which one is causing duplicates.  Is there a quick automated way to find out which table is the problem table (aka the one with duplicate rows)?

Comment: No. You have to look at the underlying query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a variation of SpectralGhost's technique to get this working even though neither method really solves the problem of avoiding the manual checking of each table for duplicate rows.
My variation was to use a divide and conquer method of commenting out the joins instead of 
commenting out each one individually.  Due to the sheer number of joins this was much faster.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way I've found is:

1. find an example dupe
2. copy out the query
3. comment out all joins
4. add the joins back one at a time until you get another row

Whatever the join is where you started getting dupes, is where you have multiple records.

Answer (score 1):

My technique is to make a copy of the view and modify it to return every column from every table in the order of the FROM clause, with extra columns between with the table names as the column name (see example below). Then select a few rows and slowly scan to the right until you can find the table that does NOT have duplicate row data, and this is the one causing dupes.

```
SELECT
   TableA = '----------', TableA.*,
   TableB = '----------', TableB.*
FROM ...
```

This is usually a very fast way to find out. The problem with commenting out joins is that then you have to comment out the matching columns in the select clause each time, too.

Comment: With commenting out the joins I also take out all columns but the primary key for the main table and then check to see how many rows are returned.  That way I do not run into the problem of having to comment/uncomment the columns when I comment/uncomment the joins.

Comment: The problem with counting rows for me is that often there is child detail that increases the row count without there being duplicates.